# Increase input frequency circuit

Tags: modulation, high-frequency, transmitter

[image]

[image]

Referring to [this website](http://www.circuitstoday.com/simple-fm-transmitter-circuit), this circuit tries to **replicate the waveform of the input voltage and turn it into a high frequency**, I tried to simulate the circuit in LTspice, but the output is weird. May I know the solution to this?

Comment: You should name your nodes and indicate them on the schematic. You should also check that Q2 is oscillating at the appropriate carrier frequency without any input audio signal. If it doesn't oscillate at the carrier frequency then there's something wrong with your sim or something wrong with the info in the website.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is L1. The inductance is far too high for an 85 MHz resonance with say 10 pF. C5=8pF, C6=2pF injects a part of the collector voltage to the emitter so that a fixed Vb creates a few mV increase in Vbe which amplifies the collector current with a loop gain > 1 in LC resonance.

The link says "L1 can be constructed by making 4 turns of 1mm enameled copper wire on a 10mm diameter plastic former."  I estimate this as **400 nH** which at 85 MHz is j214 Ω which is getting close to free space impedance but **NOT 100 μH.**

The wire turn length = 4 * 2 π 5mm= 126 mm of 1mm magnet wire. The gap of each turn creates some interwinding capacitance which affects the result of C5 on the collector to Vcc so could be a > 1mm gap..

This can also be scaled down to 100nH air core with 30pF + 10pF vbl. while the Cap across CE remains small <=2 pF to only inject tiny pulses into the emitter-base junction.

The 2nd problem will be that your audio signal using an AC coupled pulse should have some source resistance for the negative feedback ratio to work.

Comment: The 100uH inductance is 1000 times the 0.1uH inductance in my FM transmitter.